# How do I translate from typeName strings to generics?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, generics

The context of the this question is an MVC app that takes strings and hopefully converts them to types and hands them off to generic code.

- I have a string representation of a type for input.
- I can't seem to ever put a `Type` variable inside the `<>` for a generic method.
- Does that mean I have to manually spell out all the possible cases and generic method calls? Is that the right way to do this?
- It would be cool if a `ModelBinder` could figure out the type somehow where I could have a    generic type parameter for an Action Method `public ActionResult Something<T>()`. But I don't know if that is possible.

example

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(string typeName, int? id)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
    if (type == typeof(Apple)) DoSomethingElse<Apple>(id);
    if (type == typeof(Orange)) DoSomethingElse<Orange>(id);
    //if etc ... to infinity
}
```

Comment: Reflection and generics are not good friends. Does DozsomethingElse *actually* need to be generic? It would be much easier if it just took a Type as a parameter...

Comment: @MarcGravell, I don't know. I was under the impression that using generics would be more dry and versatile than passing Types all over the place. Maybe that is a wrong impression. I would be interested to the binding work with generics personally. But I would also be interested if generics do not provide the benefits I imagined they did.

Comment: generics provide that **when you are using them at compile time**. When using them dynamically at runtime, they are a lot more fuss. MakeGenericMethod has a performance overhead, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have the type then you'd have to all it via reflection.  Assuming "DoSomethingElse" is a method in the current class:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(string typeName, int? id)
{
    Type thisType = this.GetType(); // Get your current class type
    var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
    MethodInfo doSomethingElseInfo = thisType.GetMethod("DoSomethingElse");
    MethodInfo concreteDoSomethingElse = doSomethingElseInfo.MakeGenericMethod(type);
    concreteDoSomething.Invoke(this, null);
}
```

That SHOULD work for you, although you should note, it's not going to be pretty! ;)

Comment: Do you mean the code here is not pretty, or do you mean there are other complications that will come up?

Comment: @Benjamin Sorry, I meant that you shouldn't really code like this.  You shouldn't use reflection in order to make something work generically.  The way you want to do it can't be done as the type of the object can't be known until runtime, whereas the type parameter of DoSomethingElse MUST be known at compile time. It is impossible for the compiler to tell which DoSomethingElse <T> to resolve your invocation to, so this is illegal.  If you used interfaces/base classes you could call the method on the object without knowing it's type ahead of time, but generics isn't your friend on this one...

Comment: I don't like using reflection.  It's time consuming and, well just bad IMHO.  I like your solution more: 
"var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
if (type == typeof(Apple)) DoSomethingElse<Apple>(id);"

I know it seems to be a code smell, but that's the cost of using generics in this way.  You could always put the method inside the object (not very MVVM though :-S ) and call the method using a base/interface call, but that would break your pattern.  There's no real harm in calling the method like this, it's just not something I would choose to do.  I would take the extra typing any day ;)

Comment: ok thanks, I will try it out then so that I do not keep all the extra typing to myself :)

Comment: @Benjamin you're right about only having to code the method the once, but the cost (in this case) is going to be the large if/else or case statement your have to write.  If you post your DoSomethingElse code and the types you are using online (pastebin?) then I'll take a look and see if I can find another way of doing this for you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not the one actually calling `DoSomething` because it's a controller method, there's no way to assign the type to the method such as:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething<T>(int? id)
```

Since it's IIS that invokes the method, you don't have any manner of assigning this type. Now I don't know everything about routing, so maybe it's possible with routing, but it seems unlikely to me. It looks like you're using enums, so maybe you could use enum.Parse to instantiate or create an extension method to int that is capable of determining it based on type.

Comment: He wasn't asking to change the "DoSomething" method.  He's asking how he could use generics/reflection in order to call a generic method without knowing the type he is passing into the generic method ahead of time.

Comment: Actually `int? id` would just be a database id handled by entity framework.

Comment: @Vijay: Read his last bullet statement. That's exactly what he's asking. How can AVOID reflection by employing generics. To employ generics in this case he'd have to alter the signature.

Comment: @Benjamin: In this context of a controller, `int? id` is the variable coming in as an optional parameter through the url. It probably reflects some id in the database, but OP clearly has some types this converts to (re: enum).

Comment: @JoelEtherton my mistake, I up voted your reply as an apology ;)

Comment: @Vijay: No problem. Your comment made me re-read everything because I am not immune to misreading questions :)

Comment: @JoelEtherton Me either!  I love how on StackOverflow people don't get angry over nothing!  I've only just started coming here, but right now, more than anything it's the people I like! :)  In other places you'd have gone mad and down voted everything I said for a year! lol

Comment: @JoelEtherton `typeName` basically represents the type of object stored in a database table. `id` is the PK of that record. The idea is that generics lets you deal with lots of types but you only have to code it once. The problem is that strings do not seem to easily map to generics. I do intend to try the invoke method though. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: ok, it was your buddy Vijay that pointed it out. haha thank you both :)